# Google map + browser back with last view location and zoom value

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to return the last marker view and zoom level to the user when he access some other pages and returns to the map page. Right now, I am using cookies to do it. Just want to find out if there's a conventional way of dealing with this, thanks:

When the user clicks on a marker, store them into cookies:

```
   var latLng = map.getCenter();
   var currZoom = map.getZoom();    

   $.cookie("map_center", latLng);
   $.cookie("location_id", locationid);
   $.cookie("curr_zoom", currZoom);
```

Retrieving the last viewed marker location and zoom level when he returns to the map page:

```
   var lastViewedActivity = $.cookie('location_id');
   var lastViewedMapLocation = $.cookie('map_center');
   var lastViewMapZoom = $.cookie('curr_zoom');
```

Comment: "conventional" is what works for you. What exactly is the problem with your code? As it stands now, this is **not a real question**.

Comment: Relax Marcelo, my question is if there's a more appropriate or better way of handling this. Maybe conventional is not a good word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely the way to go; your other options would be:

- storing on the server, with session or passing parameters back and forth: not appropriate here as it's more complicated and it adds nothing
- html5 local storage: not supported enough, so you'd still need a fallback on cookies